# Phased implementation tasks

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview in each cell of which is a collection view.

At the start I download html and parse it. When it is parsed, I want collection view to load.

**BUT** collection view starts searching for number of cells much earlier than html will parse.  So I have an error because for that time I don't know how many cells I need.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self dataDownLoad];  
}

-(void)dataDownLoad{
    for (int i=0; i<urlArray.count; i++) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.ru/cat/%@",urlArray[i]]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                             timeoutInterval:60.0];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (response) {
                //--------------//-----------

                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[aNodes getAttributeNamed:@"href"], @"a", [imgNodes getAttributeNamed:@"src"], @"img", nil];

                [catArray addObject:dict];

                [contentArray addObject:catArray];

            }
        }];
    }

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [contentArray[collectionView.tag] count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning `0` until your data is loaded. Once your data is loaded, tell your collection view to `reloadData`.

Comment: but how i can ask for collection view if it is in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Return `0` and wait for the request to finish and your data to process then call `reloadData()`
You might need to create an Outlet to reference the collection view so you can call `reloadData()`

```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
        {
        [self dataDownLoad];  
        }

    -(void)dataDownLoad{
        for (int i=0; i<urlArray.count; i++) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.test.ru/cat/%@",urlArray[i]]];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                 timeoutInterval:60.0];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                if (response) {
//--------------//-----------

                        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[aNodes getAttributeNamed:@"href"], @"a", [imgNodes getAttributeNamed:@"src"], @"img", nil];

                        [catArray addObject:dict];

                            [contentArray addObject:catArray];

                       //ADD THIS PART:
                        [collectionView reloadData];

                }
            }];
        }



-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [contentArray[collectionView.tag] count];//this should return 0 the first time and be called again when reloadData() is called.
}
```

Comment: but how i can ask for collection view if it is in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath